# Loop running wrong number of times

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to remove certain values of a list doing a simple for loop. The loop seems to run 1 less time than expected. If I run children.length+1 it gives me an out of bounds error. Can someone see why this is occurring by simply looking at this code?

```js
var children = document.getElementsByClassName("w-dyn-items")[0].children;
console.log(children.length) // 5
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var tableChild = children[i];
    console.log(i, children[i]); // i = 0,1,2,3
    id = tableChild.getElementsByClassName("text-block-3")[0];
    console.log(id.textContent, msid)
    if (id.textContent != msid) {
        children[i].remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `for (var i = 0; i <= children.length; i++)` that will check if `i` is less than OR equal to.

Comment: You already defined `tableChild`, why use `children[i]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're removing children, once you remove a child, `children.length` decreases., and when you check the next index, you will "skip" a row.  You just need to decrement `i` when you remove:

```
if (id.textContent != msid){
    children[i].remove();
    i--;
}
```

E.g.

```
let arr = [0, 1, 2]
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // i = 0; arr = [0, 1, 2]; arr[i] === 0;
    // i = 1; arr = [1, 2]; arr[i] === 2; we skipped 1
    if (arr[i] !== 2) arr[i].remove();
}
```

Comment: thanks I completely forgot about that... appreciate the help.